# Invalid dispatch configuration for modules in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, module, war, ear

I am testing the new feature called [Modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/), that Google introduced recently in Google App Engine.

I have a dispatch.xml file with several entries and when I try to upload, it gives me this error:

> Beginning interaction for module default...
>
> 0% Uploading dispatch entries.
>
> Unable to update dispatch entries for app: Error posting to URL: 
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/dispatch/update?module=default&app_id=xxxxxxxx&version=beta&
>
> 400 Bad Request
>
> Validation error: Invalid dispatch configuration - too many rules '12'
>   exceeds the maximum of '10'.

I don't find anywhere informations regarding limits for the dispatch configuration file. Am I missing something? 
I took the dispatch.xml file from the Google documentation, so there should not be any mistakes

Comment: Is this a free or paid app? There's a limit on the number of modules a free app can have (5 maybe?), so it wouldn't be surprising that there was also a limit on the number of dispatch rules

Comment: Paid app. Well I can understand a limit regarding the number of modules .. But the number of dispatch options seem to me a bit strange. In the end it is a regex

Answer (score 1):

It is written in the docuemtation the limit regarding the number of rules.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing#dispatch_file) you can see:

> The dispatch file can contain up to 10 routing rules. When specifying the url string, neither the hostname nor the path can be longer than 100 characters.